# promise all not working as expected while working with list

Tags: node.js

I want the callback to return the response when promise all finishes. I am getting the response before promise all. Batch List is empty in response, as it is returned before promise all.

```
getByReferenceID(object, mode, limit, lastEvaluatedKey, callback){
        var results = {};
        var requestList = [];
        var batchList = [];
        var response = {};
       new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.getRequestList(object, limit, lastEvaluatedKey,function (err, result) {
                console.log(result);
                results = result;
                if(err) {
                    reject();
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        }).then(async () =>
        {
            requestList = requestList.concat(results.items);
            const runAsyncFunctions = async () => {
            var promises = [];
                requestList.map(async request => {
                    var promise = await this.getBatchList(request.requestID.S, mode, null, null, function(err, result) {
                        batchList = batchList.concat(result.items);
                    });
                    promises.concat(promise);
                });
               await Promise.all(
                    promises
                ).then(()=>{
                   response = {
                       "requests": requestList,
                       "batches": batchList,
                       "lastEvaluatedKey": results.LastEvaluatedKey
                   };
                   callback("", response);
               }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                });
            };
            await runAsyncFunctions();

        }).catch((error) => {
            callback(error, response);
        });
    }
```

Comment: oh my, you don't use `await` and `then` together. I suggest you clarify your promise concepts and usage of `async/await` and `then block` and all.

Answer (score 1):

promises is not an array of promises.

The line

```
var promise = await this.getBatchList(request.requestID.S, mode, null, null, function(err, result) {
    batchList = batchList.concat(result.items);
});
```

is executed later then

```
callback("", response)
```

I guess you want to do something like this

```
var promises = [];

for (const request of requestList) {
  const promise = this.getBatchList(request.requestID.S, mode, null, null, function (err, result) {
    batchList = batchList.concat(result.items);
  });

  promises.push(promise);
}

await Promise.all(
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing it is:

```
getByReferenceID(object, mode, limit, lastEvaluatedKey, callback){
        var results = {};
        var requestList = [];
        var batchList = [];
        var response = {};
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.getRequestList(object, limit, lastEvaluatedKey,function (err, result) {
                console.log(result);
                results = result;
                if(err){
                    reject(err);
                }
                else{
                    resolve();
                }
            });
            return results;
        }).then(() =>
        {
            requestList = requestList.concat(results.items);
            var iteration =0;
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                for (let request of requestList) {
                    console.log(request.requestID.S);
                    this.getBatchList(request.requestID.S, mode, null, null, function (err, result) {
                        iteration++;
                        batchList = batchList.concat(result.items);
                        if(iteration === requestList.length)
                        {
                            resolve();
                        }
                        if(err)
                        {
                            reject();
                        }
                    });
                }

            }).then(()=>{
                response = {
                    "requests": requestList,
                    "batches": batchList,
                    "lastEvaluatedKey": results.LastEvaluatedKey,
                };
                callback("", response);
            }).catch((error) => {
                callback(error, response);
            });

        }).catch((error) => {
            callback(error, response);
        });

    }
```